# Why won't this code compile?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, move-semantics

With `const`, as indicated by the comment, msvc 11 and g++ 4.7.0 refuse to compile this:

```
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr
#include <utility>      // std::move
using namespace std;

struct CommandLineArgs
{
    typedef unique_ptr<
        wchar_t const* const [],
        void(*)( wchar_t const* const* )
        > PointerArray;

    //PointerArray const  args;         // Oops
    PointerArray        args;
    int const           count;

    static wchar_t const* const* parsed(
        wchar_t const       commandLine[],
        int&                count
        )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    static void deallocate( wchar_t const* const* const p )
    {
    }

    CommandLineArgs(
        wchar_t const   commandLine[]   = L"",
        int             _               = 0
        )
        : args( parsed( commandLine, _ ), &deallocate )
        , count( _ )
    {}

    CommandLineArgs( CommandLineArgs&& other )
        : args( move( other.args ) )
        , count( move( other.count ) )
    {}
};

int main()
{}
```

The error messages do not seem to be particularly informative, but here's g++'s output:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'CommandLineArgs::CommandLineArgs(CommandLineArgs&&)':
main.cpp:38:38: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr&) [w
ith _Tp = const wchar_t* const; _Dp = void (*)(const wchar_t* const*); std::unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr]'
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/memory:86:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\program files (x86)\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:402:7: error: declared here
```

Why?

Comment: -1, OP didn't put an effort to make it SSCE, if `CommandLineArgs` would contain only const member and move ctor, the issue would be obvious.

Comment: @Abyx: I told you in chat that you don't have to submit ever more evidence. it's enough. please let it rest: it hurts me (on your behalf). ok, explanation for you: the error message is produced when the class only contains const members. what does that tell you, if anything?

Comment: here is a SSCE - http://ideone.com/VOlcA , compiler error clearly says what's wrong there.

Comment: @Abyx: your point seems to be that with different code producing a different error message, that different question would not be worth asking. i agree.

Comment: actually it's the same code, reduced to the point where error message is way more clear. There are only meaningful lines, and `std::move` replaced with its (expected) implementation. Then we see that such `std::move` can't be used there, and we understand why it falls back to copying.

Comment: it's not insane. And it's OK to get some downvotes for not trying to solve your question before posting it, nor helping us to solve it (by providing a good, clean, minimal example). You know, people just don't like to see such a wall-of-text, with cryptic `(_)`, non-trivial types like `wchar_t const* const []`, and stuff which has nothing to do with the issue, like that deleter. Like I said before, `unique_ptr<void>` would be enough here.

Comment: Right, you could solve it by yourself, but you preferred to drop that wall-of-text here. Why do you think that `wchar_t const* const []` is a relevant detail? Did you tried to replace it with `int` and check if you get the same compiler error? Why do you think that deleter is a part of problem? Did you tried to remove it?

Comment: @Abyx: the OP doesn't *know* what the problem and is not in a position to remove details. You are wrong, *Wrong*, ***WRONG***, that the OP here should remove details. The OP is the one least qualified to remove details, because the OP doesn't know the answer to the question, so does not know what's relevant. It's an very small complete compilable example. To you such small example may be a "wall of text", and you wish for it to be incomplete and with possibly relevant details removed. Your idea is not just wholly impractical, as I wrote it's ***WRONG***. That means. WRONG. Not to mention dumb.

Comment: IMO, the OP *must* try to solve the problem by himself before posting it anywhere. period. Regarding to "details", again, the problem is the compiler error at specific line. Thus you may remove any parts of code, as long as you get same error at same place. If you removed something and still get same error - it means that the thing you removed was irrelevant to the problem. It just like you reduce `2*x = 6*y` to `x = 3*y` in mathematics.

Comment: @Abyx: the OP, known as a pretty competent C++ programmer, presumably did try to solve the problem before posting it. E.g., the empty body of `main`, and artifacts of the code belonging in a wider context, implies that this is a pared down example. You *should* have been able to figure that out. It happens that even pretty competent people are unable to see things that they themselves would see as "obvious" earlier or later. This has happened also with the highest authorities in the C++ world, e.g. Herb (auto_ptr), Bjarne (void main, +more), etc. You might think about that, perhaps?

Comment: you could try harder, write a better question end get 5 more upvotes instead of that downvotes. btw, you always can edit the question.

Comment: uhm, this conversation leads to nowhere, we can't convince each other and even SO says it's too chatty for comments. We can continue it in the Lounge, if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not move const object. The error is because of your move constructor.

The unique_ptr, has deleted copy constructor and move constructor declared as :

```
unique_ptr( const unique_ptr & other );
unique_ptr( unique_ptr && other );
```

Since your unique_ptr is declated const, it picks copy constructor, not move constructor.

Comment: I don't see anything in the standard that requires *how* the implementation stops `unique_ptr` from being CopyConstructible, only a statement that it is not CopyConstructible. So is the deleted copy ctor (a) an implementation detail, (b) the only way to satisfy the requirements of the standard, (c) explicitly required in the standard but I missed it? Could an implementation conform with (for example) a copy ctor declared private but not defined?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `other.args` looks to me a bit const around the edges.

Comment: @Steve: oh why didn't I see that?

Comment: Oh, so one conclusion is that `const` members can foil efficient move semantics. Hm.

Comment: Yes, I think that in effect the const-ness of a const member trumps the unspecified-ness of the state after moving.

Comment: @SteveJessop Maybe I don't understand your questions, but [unique.ptr]/5 tells `Each object of a type U instantiated from the unique_ptr template speciﬁed in this subclause has the strict
ownership semantics, speciﬁed above, of a unique pointer. In partial satisfaction of these semantics, each such U is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but is not CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.`

Comment: @BЈовић: that's the bit I found. My question is, "is there any way other than deleting the copy ctor, for an implementation to satisfy the requirement that unique_ptr not be CopyConstructible?". If so, then I think it's a bit odd that this has been left to the implementation. If not, then I think it's a bit odd that `unique_ptr` has a constructor that must be declared (albeit declared deleted), but that isn't listed under "constructors" in the definition of the class in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

No copy c-tor that have signature unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&);

Comment: That's what the eror mesage says, yes; my question is why.